# Return the user and token , by a request in Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel-9

I'm making a request with Laravel to check if the user token is still valid, but it doesn't return the user from my users table, but it returns the information from the personal_access_tokens table, I know this isn't quite an error but as I'm new to this area I'm having trouble knowing how to return the user the token belongs to.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I ended up giving up on doing this in Laravel and created a rule to validate in my application, so it worked!
Thank you again.